# Merging .NET Standard assemblies

Tags: .net, .net-core, .net-standard

I couldn't find any documentation on the possibility to merge two (or more) .NET Standard assemblies, either using *ILRepack* or *ILMerge*.
Both of the tools are merging assemblies of the .NET profiles 2.0, 3.5 and 4.0, but I believe they're not compatible with .NET standard profile.

Has anyone any experience with that? Anyone can point to any documentation of the feature?

Thanks!

Comment: Can't say I've tried either of those with .NET Standard, but I do know Microsoft is planning to support merging in dependencies as a standard compiler feature in an upcoming release.

Comment: Both tools are open source right now at GitHub. So even if they don't support such merging now, you can go ahead and make it work. At least, it is still MSIL manipulation and MSIL hasn't changed.

Comment: @CoryNelson it seems that you are referring to .NET Native. It still has a long way to come to the arena.

Answer (score 7):

Not sure if you are still interested but I was able to get this to work with ILRepack a while back.

The main trick was adding a path for `NETStandard.Library` to `RepackOptions.SearchDirectories`. Can be as simple as pointing at your nuget dir. Something like: `\.nuget\packages\NETStandard.Library\2.0.0\build\netstandard2.0\ref`

Otherwise, would get exceptions like "Failed to resolve assembly: 'netstandard, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51'"

Comment: If you use the .csproj to configure the task, you can add an ItemGroup element with: <NetStandardLocation Include="$(NuGetPackageRoot)NETStandard.Library\2.0.1\build\netstandard2.0\ref" /> in it and include it an Exec element with /lib:@(NetStandardLocation) in the command args